# dropdown menu behind carouFredSel slider

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, slideshow, caroufredsel

I made some changes on one of my projects. I added a jQuery slideshow using **carouFredSel** plugin. But after that, all submenus of top menu bar are fallen behind the slideshow images.
I've applied `z-index:1000` to all items inside top menu. But the problem did not solve.
Could you give me a solution to solve this problem?
URL: www.parniaweb.ir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply `z-index` to the menu items, items become positioned in relation to the menu itself, not in relation to the overall layout. You need to position an item that is on the same or higher level in DOM hierarchy as the slider. I would suggest `#top`:

```
#top {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```